# Cusomize the AppBar in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am using a drawer and in the AppBar actions there are two flat buttons.

[image]

I would like make it have an oval background. Like this:

[image]

I tried wrapping the `AppBar` in a `PreferredSize` but I couldn't get the buttons to center vertically. Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I was missing a `SafeArea` widget.

```
PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(50.0), // h
          child: SafeArea(
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
                color: Colors.black54,
              ),
              child: AppBar(
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to create a custom `AppBar` with a stateless widget that implements `PreferredSize`:

```dart
class CustomAppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {

  CustomAppBar({...}) : preferredSize = Size.fromHeight(60.0);

  @override
  final Size preferredSize;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomBar();
  }
}
```

You should then be able to create a custom app bar with your preferred style and widget placement

Comment: I don't understand how to use this. What is `CustomBar()` supposed to be? Another AppBar? And what is `CustomAppBar({...})`? Do I need to pass something instead of {...}? And do I add the `navbar:` in this class?

Comment: `CustomAppBar` was supposed to replace the regular `AppBar` in your `Scaffold` and the `...` was to signify arguments. As it was an example I didn't put any in. In any case it looks like you found the solution by using safe area, nice work! Sorry I couldn't be of help